# How to read a nested json file into a database (with Pentaho)

Tags: database, pentaho

I have a json file and I have to load it into a database

json file:

```
{"events":[
{"Id":"1","Name":"event1","activities":{"run":"33","swim":"36","walk":"33"}},
{"Id":"2","Name":"event2","activities":{"run":"45","swim":"80","walk":"11"}},
{"Id":"3","Name":"event3","activities":{"run":"23","swim":"64","walk":"42"}}
]}
```

activityType table (is already filled)

```
activityId  activity
1           run
2           swim
3           walk
```

Table that I have to fill (event_activity) 
the Id of the table is an auto increment field so I need not consider with it.

[image: event_activityTable]

I have to use the "JSON input" step. But I don't know which path I should use

[image: PentahoSnapShot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the website that helped me becoming familiar with the JSONPath. Once you know the JSONPath, it becomes easier for you to pull the fields from a JSON document. I started with this:

http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

After this, go to the JSON input step and open the "fields" tab. Here you will enter the JSONPath. In your case, you can extract it like this:
[image]

Just like run, you can extract "swim" and "walk".

Hope it helps! 
Thanks :)